# how can I fix negative values at the moment when I want to insert items?

Tags: php, datatables, codeigniter-3

i am working with datatables and codeigniter, but at the moment when i insert items from my plus button from datatables , the plug is still counting and when datatables column is equal to zero then count negative numbers, however my backed doesn't allow negative numbers , and return me unsigned error . the problem is giving me negative numbers is this line

```
columnas[2].innerHTML = (columnas[2].innerHTML - 1);
```

how can I fix it?

controllers

```
public function add_cart(){
        $this->session->set_userdata("carrito", $this->sale->checar_existe_carrito());
        $response = array(
            "status" => 0
        );
        $producto_actual = array(
            'id' => $this->input->post("id"),
            'name' => $this->input->post("name"),
            'qty' => $this->input->post("qty"),
            'price' => $this->input->post("price"),
        );
        $tipo_operacion = $this->input->post("tipo_operacion");
        $producto = $this->products->get_product(md5($producto_actual['id']));
        $valor_compara = $tipo_operacion == 1 ? $producto->stock - $producto_actual['qty'] : $producto->stock - ($producto_actual['qty'] - $this->sale->get_current_cart_qty($this->session->carrito, $producto_actual['id']));
        if ($producto->stock == 0) {
               $response['error'] = "There is not enough stock of this product to add to cart";
               $this->json(array('error' => $response['error']));
        }else{
            echo 'bien';
        }
    }
```

ajax

```
$('#btn-search').click(function (e) {
    BootstrapDialog.show({
        title: 'Search Product',
        message: function (dialog) {
            var $message = $('<div></div>');
            var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
            $message.load(pageToLoad);
            return $message;
        },
        data: {
            pageToLoad: URL_GET_VIEW_SEARCH_PRODUCT
        },
        onshown: function (dialog) {
            $('#example').DataTable({
                lengthChange: false,
                responsive: true,
                ajax: {
                    url: URL_GET_DATATABLE,
                    type: 'POST',
                },
                columnDefs: [{
                    targets: 4,
                    data: null,
                    defaultContent: "<a href='#' class='add_product'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span></a>"
                }]
            });
            $('.dataTable').on('click', 'tbody tr td a.add_product', function () {
                var columnas = $(this).parent().parent().children();
                var id = columnas[0].innerHTML;
                var name = columnas[1].innerHTML;
                var qty = 1;
                var price = columnas[3].innerHTML;
                add_cart(id, name, qty, price, 1);
                columnas[2].innerHTML = (columnas[2].innerHTML - 1);
            });

        }
    });
});
```

stock_column_negative
[image: stock_column_negative]

Comment: Do you want that column to display a zero instead of a negative value, or to prevent the process of adding a product if the value is currently zero?

Comment: yes I want to display zero instead of negative value. the database wont allow u adding negative values , but however the datatables is still count.

Answer (score 0):

Since you just need to change the behaviour of changing the innerHTML value to a negative value, it's just a case of setting the value as either the new value or zero if the value is less than zero.

```
var myNewValue = (columnas[2].innerHTML - 1) < 0 ? 0 ; (columnas[2].innerHTML - 1);
```

If the resulting value is less than zero, make it zero, if it is not, use the result.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var printResult = document.getElementById('result');
  var getNumber = document.getElementById('number');
  printResult.innerHTML = (getNumber.value - 1) < 0 ? 0 : (getNumber.value - 1)
};
```

```html
<input type="number" id="number">
<button id="button" onclick="myFunction()">push</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```